# NASM rep nop assembles as pause

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, x86-64, nasm

Consider the following function which is written in x86-assembly

```
foo:
        rep
        nop
        ret
```

Using NASM to assemble the code and disassemble it with `gdb` we have:

```
(gdb) disas foo
Dump of assembler code for function foo:
   0x0000000000000610 <+0>:     pause  ;pause ????
   0x0000000000000612 <+2>:     ret    
   0x0000000000000613 <+3>:     nop    WORD PTR cs:[rax+rax*1+0x0]
   0x000000000000061d <+13>:    nop    DWORD PTR [rax]
End of assembler dump.
```

It uses the `pause` instruction which was not presented in the original assembly. Why does it work this way? Is that an intentional documented behavior of NASM? So in case some earlier x86 `cpu`s do not have `pause` we can just use `rep nop`?

Comment: Yes, Intel chose `rep nop` as the encoding for `pause` so it could be used without checking for CPU support; older CPUs decode it as `nop`.  Read the manual for pause.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pause

Comment: @PeterCordes Manual entry for `rep` does not even specify it to be used with `nop`.  Precisely _The REP prefix can be added to the INS, OUTS, MOVS, LODS, and STOS instructions, and the REPE, REPNE, REPZ, and REPNZ prefixes can be added to the CMPS and SCAS instructions._ So that was the reason I considered the `rep nop` as a feature of NASM.

Comment: @PeterCordes Moreover it was stated that _The F3H prefix is defined for the
following instructions and undefined for the rest: F3H as REP/REPE/REPZ for string and input/output instruction. F3H is a mandatory prefix for POPCNT, LZCNT, and ADOX._ which did not mention `nop`.

Comment: Someone deleted my 2nd comment, IDK why.  I said when I google for `rep nop pause` the linked duplicate is the first hit, it fully explains the situation.  Anyway, `rep` isn't a valid prefix for `nop`, that's *why* its ignored by CPUs that don't recognize it as part of the encoding for another instruction.  That list of instructions that have `F3` as a mandatory prefix is not exhaustive; it's missing `tzcnt` and `pause`, and is also used as the [`xrelease` prefix](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xacquire:xrelease) for HLE (again because CPUs that don't recognize it ignore it).

Comment: You told NASM to output a REP prefix byte, that is a byte with the value 0xF3, followed by a NOP opcode byte, that is a byte with the value 0x90. You told NASM to output the byte sequence `F3 90` so that's what it did.  NASM did not at any point consider whether or not this was a valid instruction sequence or not. It did not change `rep` `nop` from a invalid instruction sequence to an valid one. It just happened to be one, whether you intended it to be or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not so much NASM assembling REP NOP into a PAUSE instruction as GDB decoding the `F3` and `90` bytes that make up the REP prefix and the NOP instruction respectively as the PAUSE instruction.

That's because the PAUSE instruction is also encoded as `F3 90`.  This is intentional documented behaviour of x86 CPUS, so that CPUs without the PAUSE instruction will treat it as a NOP. It has nothing to with NASM or GDB other than they assemble and disassemble instructions according to the CPU documentation.

Comment: But the concern is that `rep` is not specified to be used with `nop`: [rep docs](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rep:repe:repz:repne:repnz). Percisely _The F3H prefix is defined for the following instructions and **undefined for the rest**: F3H as REP/REPE/REPZ for string and input/output instruction. F3H is a mandatory prefix for POPCNT, LZCNT, and ADOX._

Comment: @St.Antario: As part of the encoding for `pause`, it's *not* acting as a `rep` prefix.

Comment: @BeeOnRope The details of prefixes application is blurred across the manual. But searching through the manual VOLs I did not find that if a prefix is not used with an instruction then it is ignored. Moreover `lock` is also invalid prefix for `nop`, but it is explicitly stated that `#UD` is raised if `lock nop` is encountered.

Comment: You don't have to look all through the manual.  You can look at just [one page for pause itself](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pause) and see that it is encoded F3 90, i.e. the "rep" and "nop" bytes. Whether you consider this a prefix or just part of the encoding is just semantics. A good principle is that specific wins over broad: if you find a statement that says pause is encoded like this, that's likely to be right as opposed to a general description of rep prefixes, _espcially_ because the primary purpose (the repeating thing) of rep is different.

Comment: @St.Antario: For the record, inapplicable prefixes are not in general *guaranteed* to be ignored.  For example, `rep bsr` is `lzcnt`, which works differently, so if old code had been using `rep` as padding on a `bsr`, it would break on new CPUs.  But once a new instruction is introduced that uses `rep` as a mandatory prefix, Intel documents how *older* CPUs run that machine-code sequence (by ignoring the `rep` prefix), only then documenting what was already in practice true on real hardware.